# Change behavior of a UITextView according to UISwitch position

Tags: ios, uitextview, uiswitch

I have a UITextView where I've attached the Delegate protocol **textViewDidChange** to execute different actions.

Now I want to attach this Delegate method only if my UISwitch is "ON". How I can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want `textViewDidChange:` to fire only if a switch is on.  Otherwise, it shouldn't fire.

I would not recommend setting and unsetting the delegate in order to accomplish this.

Instead, you can bail out of the method:

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {
    if (!self.switch.isOn) {
        return; // bail out
    }
    // your "different actions" code
}
```

Or, depending on your style, you can do something like:

```
- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView {
    if ([self shouldRespondToChangeInTextView:textView])
        [self respondToChangeInTextView:textView];
    }
}

- (BOOL)shouldRespondToChangeInTextView:(UITextView *)textview {
    return self.switch.isOn;
}

- (void)respondToChangeInTextView:textView:(UITextView *)textView {
    // your "different actions" code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside your delegate method you can just put all your code inside an `if` statement, saying `if switch.on {...`.  If the switch's `on` property is set to true it'll execute the rest of your code.  Otherwise it'll just skip it.